# C# stopwatch problems

Tags: c#, stopwatch

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int index = 1; index < timeNum; index++)
    {
        stopwatch.Restart(); 
        //MessageBox.Show(“test”);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);  
        pictureBox1.Image = list1[index * 2];
        pictureBox2.Image = list1[index * 2 + 1];
        stopwatch.Stop();
    }
 }
```

i want every other period of time change the images of the two picturebox, but the program is not performed automatically,anyone can help,thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with `Stopwatch`? You aren't using it for anything.

Comment: Yeah a stopwatch measures time, I think you're looking for a timer.

Comment: What is your question exactly? :)

Answer (score 0):

Like in the comments, you don't need a Stopwatch.
It may be the case that timeNum is <= 1.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    //Default the pictures first
    pictureBox1.Image = list1[0];//Verify that this exists as well
    pictureBox2.Image = list1[1];//Verify that this exists as well

    if(timeNum <= 1){
        MessageBox.Show(“oHs Noes!!!!!!”);
    }
    else{
        for (int index = 1; index < timeNum; index++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);  
            pictureBox1.Image = list1[index * 2]; //You will need to verify that this exists as well
            pictureBox2.Image = list1[index * 2 + 1];//You will need to verify that this exists as well
        }
    }
}
```

"the program is not performed automatically," --> What does this mean? 
I'm assuming that you want it to work. The logic is almost there.

Comment: This answer (and the other) is like offering a bogosort on a sorting algorithm question.

Comment: There was no "specific" question ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean refresh picturebox automaticlly. Here it is.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int index = 1; index < timeNum; index++)
    {
        //stopwatch.Restart(); // as they say, you don't need this
        //MessageBox.Show(“test”);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);  
        pictureBox1.Image = list1[index * 2];
        pictureBox2.Image = list1[index * 2 + 1];
        //stopwatch.Stop();
        pictureBox1.Update();
        pictureBox2.Update();
    }
}
```